# For radio input type onclick event not working inside form tag

Tags: javascript

I got stuck to what I think is silly. But now I have tried every combination but not able to find out what is going on.

onclick inside input type radio is not working when I put input type inside a form. But when I delete form tag it works. Also I have seen a code where onclick work inside a form tag but not working when I write.

This is not working:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function action(str){
        document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML=str
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="radio" value="ping" name="rb" onclick="action(this.value)">Ping
        <input type="radio" value="card" name="rb" onclick="action(this.value)">Card
        <input type="radio" value="temp" name="rb" onclick="action(this.value)">Temprature
        <p id="test1">radio will be displayed here</p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I remove form it works.

Comment: Edit your post, put your code into code highlight

Comment: Show your HTML as well.

Answer (score 2):

change the name of your function `action`

try this :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function action123(str){
        document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML=str
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="radio" value="ping" name="rb" onclick="action123(this.value);">Ping
    <input type="radio" value="card" name="rb" onclick="action123(this.value);">Card
    <input type="radio" value="temp" name="rb" onclick="action123(this.value);">Temprature
    <p id="test1">radio will be displayed here</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use inline event functions anymore. Use event listeners:

```
radios = document.getElementsByName("rb");
for(i=0; i<radios.length; i++) {
    radios[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
       document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = e.target.value;
    });
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmXjD/2)

Answer (score 0):

"action" seems to be a blocked namesspace for forms

try sth like

```
<script>   
function otherName(str){
document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML=str;
}
</script>
 <form name="form">
    <input type="radio" value="ping" name="rb" onclick="otherName(this.value)" />Ping
    <input type="radio" value="card" name="rb" onclick="otherName(this.value)" />Card
    <input type="radio" value="temp" name="rb" onclick="otherName(this.value)" />Temprature
<p id="test1">radio will be displayed here</p>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/waeqT/